# Create raster from grid of data points

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, rasterization

I have an Excel spreadsheet with the columns longitude, latitude and TR. I add them as XY data to ArcMap with long as the x data, lat as the y data and TR as the value.  This gives me a 12 x 12 series of points, representing a grid of data values in the Arctic.

I want to the convert this to a raster. I've tried using both Point To Raster and Feature To Raster.  Point to Raster gives me an unknown 9999 error and Features to Raster gives me an `000861 error - 'Sheet1 is not valid'`.

In both cases I enter `TR` in the 'field' section and leave the cell size to default

Comment: After you load the table into ArcMap and then displaying XY data, is there a point layer (usually has a name like the table but with Events after)?  Is that what you're putting into the Feature to Raster tool?  If so, the other thing could be the projection - make sure that you're setting that, otherwise the points won't have reference.  If it's just general Lat/Long information, you can use Geographic Systems\World Geodetic System 1984

Comment: Try exporting as a *real* table, either a DBF or geodatabase table then exporting the events as *real* points (don't forget to set the spatial reference) before running point/feature to raster.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with some random coordinates.

```
LAT:36.932108, 36.93253001, 36.93286302, 36.93288297, 36.93236698, 36.93219901
LON: -94.859716, -94.85966401, -94.85955002, -94.85918901, -94.85913604, -94.85908097
```

1. Add the data to ArcMap
2. Display XY data (X field = Lon, Y fild = Lat and set the coordiante system)
   [image]
3. Export the data 
   [image]
4. Use the "Feature to Raster" Tool (Input features = exported output from step 3) 
   [image]

I don't get an error message by doing all of the above, so maybe check that you are properly defining your coordinate system.